# Swift check for nil in optional array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an Optional array and need to check a member for nil. Unfortunately that doesn't work like I have expected it to do. It seems like I have to unwrap it however at runtime I don't know whether the value in question is a String, an Int, another array etc. so casting doesn't help (I think)

```
var nilString: String? = nil

let arr = [1, nilString] as [Any]?

print(nilString)
print(arr?[1])

if (arr?[1] == nil) {
    print("is nil") // doesn't work
}

if case Optional<Any>.none = arr?[1] {
    print("nil")     //would expect this one 
} else {             //but
    print("not nil") //<-- gets printed
}
```

Alternative ideas on the structure are also welcomed.

Comment: You just need to change your array type to `let arr: [Any?] = [1, nilString]`. You have declared your array type as optional instead of declaring its elements.

Comment: Can you share why you think you need to use an array of Any? This seems like a code smell and there is possibly a much better way to deal with the problem than using an array of Any?

Comment: @LeoDabus moving the question mark in the brackets works for me. I've edited the question so your answer would fit. Write it and I will mark as correct, thank you

Comment: @Fogmeister bad code. It's literally that, at the moment during prototyping there are a lot of different types and nested types to take care of as the model isn't done yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem there is that you have declared your `Array` type as optional instead of declaring its elements.  You just need to change your array declaration to`[Any?]`. Note that the use of `Any` it is not useful in most situations. I've been coding in Swift for more than 5 years and I've never needed to declare an element type as `Any`.